# Siri saved my reminder on the shared "family" list. How can I prevent this from happening again?

Tags: icloud, siri, reminders, privacy, family-sharing

I asked Siri to remind me to purchase some personal items at the pharmacy, and right at that time the reminder appeared, I got an awkward phone call from a family member asking me why my reminders appeared on their phone.

I discovered this when I opened "reminders" on the Mac. Somehow the only reminder list I have is "Family". That means every alert I had appeared on their devices.   every.one.

Besides being exposed to a complete lack of privacy, how can I stop default reminders, of any source, from appearing on the family iCloud group?

Examples: Email, calendar, events, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings** → **Reminders** → **Default List**. This is where you can choose the list you wish to store reminders when you don't specify a location at the time of creating the reminder.

- "Remind me to …" uses the list you select as the Default List in Settings.
- "Add … to my … list" uses the list mentioned in that specific Siri command.

Comment: Mac is defaulted to "All Reminders" ... will see what phone is once it's booted up.